# Allow my docker container to make network requests

Tags: docker

I have my application running locally in a Docker container, I have published the port which I want to use to invoke its API. However, my Docker container application also needs to make other network requests to externally hosted APIs. Currently I am getting network errors when it tries to make these requests. How do I give my Docker container access to the same network that my local machine is on? Is there a Docker config I need to pass to my `docker -it -p 8080:8080` command?

Comment: What are the actual errors?  Outbound connections _should_ work fine without any special `docker run` options.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these options to your `docker run` command:

```
--network host
```

It will bind container networking directly to the Docker host’s network.

Documentation: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: (This is the "run every command with sudo and you'll never have permissions problems" answer; I wouldn't recommend it for general use.)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you David. But that was a question: how to run container in the host network space. There is no other option for that. Other (better options from the security point of view) works with different container networking, but not with host one.